# Error on custom RNN/LSTM with multiple inputs

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, cnn, lstm

I want to implement a custom RNN/LSTM model similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54231440/define-custom-lstm-cell-in-keras). The model should take two separate vectors as input and process them. I was following keras tutorial to implement a [custom keras layer](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/) and inputting two vectors a and b as a list [a,b] to the layer as shown below.

```
import keras
from keras.layers.recurrent import RNN
import keras.backend as K

class MinimalRNNCell(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        self.units = units
        self.state_size = units
        super(MinimalRNNCell, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def build(self, input_shape):
        print(type(input_shape))
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[0][-1], self.units),
                                      initializer='uniform',
                                      name='kernel')
        self.recurrent_kernel = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.units, self.units),
            initializer='uniform',
            name='recurrent_kernel')
        self.built = True
    def call(self, inputs, states):
        prev_output = states[0]
        h = K.dot(inputs[0], self.kernel)
        output = h + K.dot(prev_output, self.recurrent_kernel)
        return output, [output]

# Let's use this cell in a RNN layer:
cell = MinimalRNNCell(32)
a = keras.Input((None, 5))
b = keras.Input((None, 5))
layer = RNN(cell)
y = layer([a,b])
```

But I am getting the error TypeError: `'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` at

```
self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[0][-1], self.units),
                                          initializer='uniform',
                                          name='kernel')
```

Also the type of the input_shape is showing as `<type 'tuple'>`, not a list.
Whats wrong I am doing and how to overcome this error. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I think, `input_shape[0]` is `None`. Based on my understanding, you will pass a matrix of size (Batch_size, Time steps, dim of each time step data) to an RNN cell. And while creating your architecture, `input_shape[0]` will give the batch size (if you mentioned what is the batch size in input layer, if not you will get `None`). Even if you mention batch size, it will be an integer and you can't index the integers so you are getting that error.